# Passing parameter through all MVC4 pages

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

In my application there's the need of passing out a specific parameter, when it exists,  through all pages.

What is the best way of I can do this?
There's some function that is called whenever I do an GET or POST requisition, in which I can verify if the parameter exist and persist it?

Comment: Can you post the existing function(s) and show an example of what you've already tried?  Perhaps your way is the best already.

Comment: Can you not just store the parameter in the session somewhere and access it where its required?

Comment: I don't know why the downvote. There's something wrong with my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an action filter like the one below.

```
public sealed class ScaffoldActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
    {

        public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
        {
                var model = filterContext.Controller.ViewData.Model as PageModelBase;
                  // Whatever you want to do.
                model.myParam = "Im available in all views";
        }
    }
```

Next register it to run on every request. Look in app_start/filterconfig.cs
and and it like this.

```
filters.Add(new ScaffoldActionFilter());
```

Now just return the standard pagebasemodel or a derived type from every view and you have what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @RubbleFord! By doing this, there's no need to put the [ScaffoldActionFilter] on every action, right?

Comment: That's right, your registering it as a global filter hence it runs for everything. One thing to note is you may need to setup exclusions for jsonresults or partialresults, but it's easy to do. Ask me if you get stumped. Also can you mark this as the answer :-) need the points.